# Do there exist projective realcompact covers?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

In 1958 Gleason [1] constructed projective covers in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces. These may be characterized in many ways. One description that is most interesting to me: $p:EX\to X$ is a projective cover of the compact space $X$ if for any surjection $f:P\to X$ with $P$ compact there exists the oblique arrow $\bar{p}$ as below:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
&& P \\
& \stackrel{\bar{p}}{\nearrow} & \downarrow \scriptstyle{f} \\
EX & \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}  & X 
\end{array}
$$
**Additionally** we require that if $P=EX$ and $f=p$ then $\bar p$ is a homeomorphism.

In particular every such cover $EX$ is a retract of $\beta D$ -- the Stone-Cech compactification of some discrete space $D$.

**Question:** Do we have projective covers in the category of realcompact spaces?

Of course this question is interesting only in the presence of measurable cardinals.

---

The Gleason's idea is so beautiful that it begs for generalizations, and indeed I found plenty of related literature, let me mention only a monograph [2]. However all the literature I found restricts the maps $f$ to those for which, roughly, $f^{-1}(x)$ is compact for every $x\in X$. I found only one, failed, attempt to answer the question.

Let me note that the Gleason's construction of $p$ easily generalizes, the problem is in proving the existence of $\bar{p}$ when $f^{-1}(x)$'s are far from compact. A candidate for such $p:E_\nu X\rightarrow X$ may look like this: First we ensure that $X$ has sufficiently many open subsets - let $X^\delta$ be the set $X$ with discrete topology. Let $\pi:\nu X^\delta\rightarrow X$ be the unique extension of the identity to the realcompactification of $X^\delta$. Let $X^*$ be the set $X$ with the quotient topology induced by $\pi$. Now we build the $E_\nu X$ - let $R(X^*)$ be the Boolean algebra of regular closed subsets of $X^*$, that is $C\subseteq X^*$ such that $C=\overline{\mathop{\rm int} C}$. The Stone space of ultrafilters on $R(X^*)$ is called the absolute of $X^*$ and denoted $EX^*$. It seems that our $E_\nu X$ should be the subspace of countably complete ultrafilters in $EX^*$, but I don't see how to obtain the existence of $\bar p$.

[1] A. Gleason, Projective topological spaces, Illinois J. Math. 2 (1958) 482–489.

[2] J. Porter and R. Woods, Extensions and absolutes of Hausdorff spaces. Springer-Verlag, New York, (1988) xiv+856 pp